# Multidimensional arrays PHP Error

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've been posting a single form fine to a checkout but I need my form to post multiple fields that repeat.

My array is now showing

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 65983c1c16d925e9a8cc4c4b3bdda1f5
            [item] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Brent New Product
                    [2] => Crazy Product
                )

            [unitprice] => Array
                (
                    [1] =>  100
                    [2] =>  125
                )

            [quantity] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 1
                    [2] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

But it needs to show like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 65983c1c16d925e9a8cc4c4b3bdda1f5
                (
                    [product] => Brent New Product
                    [unitprice] => 100
                    [quantity] => 1
                )
                [id] => 4326526662262
                (
                    [product] => Brent New Product2
                    [unitprice] => 140
                    [quantity] => 5
                )



        )

)
```

When my form is posted from this [page](http://3rdsector.digibug-dev.co.uk/cart/buy.php) it goes to this php script which collect all the values.

```
session_start();
$price = $_POST['price'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
$item = $_POST['item'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];

echo '<h1>Add to cart</h1>';

echo "<p>Thank you for wanting a <strong>$item</strong>!</p>";

//We define an associative array with the details of our new item
$cart_row = array(
    'id' => md5(rand()),
    'item' => $item,
    'unitprice' => $price,
    'quantity' => $quantity
);
```

Then on the cart page I wish to display the items in cart but I get nothing populating boxes, it worked before with a singal array.

```
 session_start();

 foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $item) { ?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $item['item']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $item['unitprice'];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $item['quantity']; ?></td>
  <td></td>
  <td><form id="id" name="id" method="post" action="cart.php?remove=<?php echo $item["id"] ?>">
      <input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="<? echo $item["id"]; ; ?>" />
      <input name="Submit" type="submit" class="formbox" value="remove" />
    </form></td>
</tr>
<?php   } ?>
```

Comment: Your desired output is not a valid PHP array ... missing keys for the sub-arrays

Comment: how would i fix it to use keys?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you cant have this type of array alternative you can do it like this

```
Array
(
            [65983c1c16d925e9a8cc4c4b3bdda1f5] => (
                [product] => Brent New Product
                [unitprice] => 100
                [quantity] => 1
            )
            [4326526662262] => (
                [product] => Brent New Product2
                [unitprice] => 140
                [quantity] => 5
            )
 )
```

And print it like this

```
session_start();
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $item) { ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $item['item']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $item['unitprice'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $item['quantity']; ?></td>
<td></td>
<td><form id="id" name="id" method="post" action="cart.php?remove=<?php echo $id ?>">
  <input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="<? echo $id; ?>" />
  <input name="Submit" type="submit" class="formbox" value="remove" />
  </form></td>
 </tr>
 <?php   } ?>
```

And you can fill the session with this code

```
session_start();
$cart = array();

$cart[] = array(
    $id => array(
      'product' => $product_name,
      'unitprice' => $unit_price,
      'quantity' => $quantity
    )
);

$_SESSION['cart'] = $cart;
```

Comment: Sorry this does not work, I think its to do with how the array is handled.

Comment: @BrentFrench it seems to work on my local environment. you can try this tutorial for a cart solution http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1962481

Comment: you just copy paste my code? its an example, you mast to replace my variables with yours. like $product_name, $unit_price, $quantity